# How to call LazyTableImages in my own project

Tags: ios

I am new to IOS development, and I would like to use the LazyTableImages sample in my project. I have main screen displaying a list of menus. What i want to achieve is that when a user clicks a menu on the main screen, it will start a new screen which calls the  LazyTableImages code and downloads the images.

But i have no idea how to do that.Because in the sample, the screen with the images is the first window, and in my project, it is not.It seems that I will need to move the LazyTableAppDelegate.h and LazyTableAppDelegate.m to the my own delegate file AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m files but i didnt get any luck doing that. Can anyone shed any light how should i make the change? Is there any sample code i can refer how to call one project in the other?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: post screenshot of the same. its diff to download the project and find out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

this links solve your problems.

```
   1)  [HJCache][1] 
   2)  [Video Part1][2]
   3)  [Video Part2][3]
```

Comment: u can ckeck this links http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eG9o-vDisE
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0l_l-5ZO7us